# Access violation while compiling (synthesis step) in Quartus II with Qsys System

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus, qsys

In Quartus II (V15.02) while compiling (step Analysis & Synthesis) I get the the following error when I assign the port map for the qsys design in my top entity:

**--------------------------------------------------------------**

Problem Details
Error:

> Fatal Error: Access Violation at 0000000000000000
> Module: quartus_map.exeCould not obtain stack trace

Executable: quartus_map
Comment:
None

System Information
Platform: windows64
OS name: Windows 7 // I am running Win 10 64bit
OS version: 6.2

Quartus II Information
Address bits: 64
Version: 15.0.2
Build: 153
Edition: Full Version

**--------------------------------------------------------------**

After I cleaned the project (Project -> Revision name: * -> OK) I get the mentioned error every time when i run **Analysis & Synthesis**.

My Project contains:
A VHDL File
An imported .qip file generated with QSYS. In QSYS i did generate a new hdl file after the first time the error showed up but.. same result. I deleted the db order too but still same result. The project worked

My Project contained (until the first time the error showed up) a Signal Tap and .sdc file and in the sdc file were following lines in it:

> derive_clock_uncertainty
>
> derive_pll_clocks

I deleted the .sdc file from my hard drive and tried again  - same result

I removed the .qip file commented the port map and compiled - success

Then i generated a new HDL file in QSYS.

After this i added the .qip file in Quartus II (port map still commented) -> success

Then i uncommented the port map definitions -> error

The last few logs before the error message pops up are the following:

> Info (10264): Verilog HDL Case Statement information at altera_trace_transacto_lite.v(206): all case item expressions in this case statement are onehot
> Info (10264): Verilog HDL Case Statement information at altera_trace_transacto_lite.v(314): all case item expressions in this case statement are onehot
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(92): object "state_read_addr" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(96): object "state_d1" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(98): object "in_ready_d1" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(117): object "b_startofpacket_wire" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(123): object "mem_readdata0" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(128): object "mem_readdata1" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(133): object "mem_readdata2" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10858): Verilog HDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(140): object state_waitrequest used but never assigned
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(141): object "state_waitrequest_d1" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(144): object  "out_channel" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at   alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(147): object "out_empty" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(150): object "out_error" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(285): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (1)
> Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(301): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (1)
> Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(317): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (1)
> Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_capture_width.sv(334): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (1)
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_avalon_st_adapter_data_format_adapter_0.sv(92): object "state_read_addr" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10858): Verilog HDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_avalon_st_adapter_data_format_adapter_0.sv(137): object state_waitrequest used but never assigned
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_avalon_st_adapter_data_format_adapter_0.sv(138): object "state_waitrequest_d1" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_avalon_st_adapter_data_format_adapter_0.sv(141): object "out_channel" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_avalon_st_adapter_data_format_adapter_0.sv(147): object "out_error" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_avalon_st_adapter_data_format_adapter_0.sv(290): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (2)
> Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_avalon_st_adapter_data_format_adapter_0.sv(311): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (2)
> Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_avalon_st_adapter_data_format_adapter_0.sv(334): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (2)
> Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_trfabric_avalon_st_adapter_data_format_adapter_0.sv(353): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (2)
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_host_link_jtag_h2t_timing.sv(82): object "in_ready" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_stfabric_mgmt_demux_port_adap.sv(74): object "out_channel" assigned a value but never read
> Warning (10036): Verilog HDL or VHDL warning at alt_sld_fab_alt_sld_fab_stfabric_mgmt_time_adap.sv(84): object "in_ready" assigned a value but never read
> Info (12206): 2 design partitions require synthesis
> Info (12213): Partition "Top" requires synthesis because the project database does not contain a post-synthesis netlist for this partition
> Info (12213): Partition "sld_hub:auto_hub" requires synthesis because the project database does not contain a post-synthesis netlist for this partition
> Info (12209): No design partitions will skip synthesis in the current incremental compilation

What i try to accomplish with this code is to test the 50MHz external clock which i route to the Qsys system and the 10MHz Clock from the PLL i defined in Qsys with a LED for each Signal.
Here is the code from the Top Level entity:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;


entity helloworld_lab1 is
Port (
    clk_50_max10 : in   std_logic;          --50MHz Clock
    --clk_25_max10 : in std_logic;          --25MHz Clock
    --clk_10_adc :  in std_logic;           --10MHz Clock
    cpu_resetn :    in std_logic;           -- Button 0

    
    user_led : out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
    user_pb : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  -- Middle Buttons
    
  );

end entity helloworld_lab1;


architecture behaviour of helloworld_lab1 is

        -- Qsys Component --
      component helloworld_lab is
        port (
            clk_clk                               : in  std_logic                    := 'X';             -- clk
            reset_reset_n                         : in  std_logic                    := 'X';             -- reset_n
            pio_switch_external_connection_export : in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => 'X'); -- export
            pio_led_external_connection_export    : out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);                    -- export
            pll_clock_clk                         : out std_logic                                                       -- export
        );
    end component helloworld_lab;

    Signal cycle_counter : integer range 0 to 50000000;     -- 50 MHz results in 1 Second
    Signal pll_cycle_counter : integer range 0 to 10000000;  -- 10 MHZ results in 1 Second
    Signal led_1sec : std_logic:='0';                               -- Signal LED 0
    Signal led_pll : std_logic :='1';                               -- Signal LED 4
    Signal clock_pll : std_logic;                                       -- Port Map PLL Clock
    
begin
        blink_led_1s : process (clk_50_max10)
        
        begin
            if (rising_edge(clk_50_max10)) then
                cycle_counter <= cycle_counter+1;
                if (cycle_counter>=49999999) then
                cycle_counter<=0;
                    led_1sec<=not led_1sec;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process blink_led_1s;
    
        user_led(0)<=led_1sec;
       -----------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        blink_led_pll : process (clock_pll)
        begin
            if (rising_edge(clock_pll))then
                pll_cycle_counter <= pll_cycle_counter+1;
                if (pll_cycle_counter<=9999999) then
                    pll_cycle_counter<=0;
                    led_pll<=not led_pll;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process blink_led_pll;
        
        user_led(4) <=led_pll;
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------       
    
    
    
        -----------------------------------Qsys port map-----------------------------------------------
        QSYS : component helloworld_lab
        port map (
            clk_clk                               => clk_50_max10,              
            reset_reset_n                         => cpu_resetn,              
            pio_switch_external_connection_export => user_pb(3 downto 2),       
            pio_led_external_connection_export    => user_led(3 downto 1),   
            pll_clock_clk                         => clock_pll                      
        );




end architecture behaviour;
```

And here is a screenshot of the Qsys system.

[image: Qsys Screenshot]

I would appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Comment: So i created an new project, copied the code from my top level entity 1 to 1 imported the pin assignments (.qsf) file from the previous project and imported the .qip file into the new project.
No problem with the compilation. After this i cleaned the project and the error starts to show up again.

Comment: My installation order is on another partition on my hard drive than my working directory.